# Luna Eclipse Java Lot's of Build Errors on a minor Change

Tags: java, eclipse, build-error

Whenever i do a minor change in Java Code under Eclipse. The whole units fills up with red marks (errors), and hundreds of errors appears under problems and then the project start building.At the end everything is Ok and the errors disappear but this whole process is so time consuming.This wasn't case before i upgraded eclipse from Kepler to Luna. Is there anything i can do ?

Comment: Luna have a lot of problem like that. Example i am writing webapp with jsp when i get SVN UPDATE all jsp turn red marks. When i clean red marks are still there. So i am using Kepler.